# MakeFile is not glowing like it is Executable

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, g++, findname

This is the code that i have written in my makefile. For some reason it is not letting me execute the make function. When i type "make findName", i get "make: 'findName' is up to date."

```
findName:       findName.cpp
        g++ -g findName.cpp -o findName;

clean:
        /bin/rm -f findName *.o

backup:
        #tar -zcvf bbrown.assignment4_1.tar.gz *.cpp *.h makeFile readme # will make a tar.gz
        tar -cvf bbrown.findName.tar *.cpp *.sh makeFile readme
```

Comment: Please mark code (including Makefile contents) as code by indenting it four spaces. You can do this quickly in the question/answer editor by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Why is this a problem?  Maybe `findName` _IS_ up to date.  What do you expect to happen when you type `make findName`, that is not happening?

Comment: I have no idea what glowing has to do with it, but makefiles *aren't* (ordinarily) executable.

Answer (score 1):

A message like "make: 'target' is up to date." means that `make` has decided it doesn't need to run any commands, based on the timestamps of files involved. The `make` program considers files (and phony targets) to have a tree of prerequisites, and commands associated with creating a file will only be run if the file doesn't exist or has an older timestamp than one of its prerequisites. In big projects, this helps avoid completely rebuilding everything which could take a lot of time, when only a few source files have actually changed: `make` will determine which commands are actually needed. But this does require setting up the `Makefile` with accurate prerequisites.

Your `Makefile` specifies that file `findName` has one prerequisite: `findName.cpp`. If `make` successfully creates `findName`, then you do nothing else but just type `make` again, you'll see the "up to date" message: this is a feature. If you edit and save `findName.cpp` and then run `make`, it should repeat the `g++` command.

But suppose you also have some header files you're including from `findName.cpp`, say `findName.h`. If you edit and save `findName.h` and then run `make`, you'll get "up to date", since `make` didn't know to `findName.h` has effects on `findName`. You would need to add the prerequisite to fix this:

```
findName:       findName.cpp findName.h
        g++ -g findName.cpp -o findName
```

There are various ways to automatically deal with header dependencies like that, but they get into more advanced use of `make`, and/or using other build tools.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am relatively new to this stuff and i found this to be very confusing.